# What are similar simple texture generation algorithms to XOR?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, textures

**XOR** texture is really the simplest texture generation algorithm as I see it. Well maybe except printing incrementing values in the loop.

I tried to google for basic algorithms to generate some repeating textures but didn't find any.

I know that combining trigonometric functions I can achieve some nice results but **would like to know if there are other similar techniques similar to XOR in it's simplicity**?
What I mean XOR texture is this:

[image: XOR texture]

And pseudocode is simply this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    texture[x][y] = x ^ y;
  }
}
```

Comment: there are some fractals that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at perlin noise? Google it

Comment: Yes. It is definetely what I do want, except not so quickly implementable as for example XOR filter. Despite this I appreciate your input!